# Passing a string from Obj-C to React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native

I am currently building an app in React Native and faced an issue which I seemed not to be able to resolve in my RN framewok, and I probably need to mention that I am very new with Objective-C. However, I managed to get it by calling it in my AppDelegate.m file. But how can I pass this string variable that I created in my appdelegate to my javascript files?

I took a quick gander at the NativeAppEventEmitter, but it seems to be something different. In my AppDelegate.m it looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                             annotation:annotation
                  ];
  NSString *fbAccessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;
  return handled;
}
```

Looking at the NativeAppEventEmitter trick given by RN I have tried to implement it. But it complains alot about my bridge.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "RCTRootView.h"

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

#import "RCTBridge.h"

#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

@synthesize bridge = _bridge;
```

Where I in my `AppDelegate.h` declare it as: `@property (nonatomic) NSString *bridge;`

But when I try to utilise the `eventDispatcher` it gives me the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass some data when starting an app using using `initialProperties`. I think it's the best solution in your case. You can pass your token on the `RCTRootView` and then grab it from `props`. There is a good example in [RN docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html#passing-properties-from-native-to-react-native).
Alternatively you can [send an event](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#sending-events-to-javascript) with embedded data.

Comment: The data will only occur when I perform the login in my app. So im guessing it will be empty when the app is starting. Would that be an issue?

Comment: I've updated my answer to fit your case. This may be not related to the question itself but you can use [`react-native-fbsdk`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) and avoid native-JS communication is this case. You can find a tutorial on how to configure it properly [here](https://blog.callstack.io/login-users-with-facebook-in-react-native-4b230b847899#.kyme1j6du).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to make that work then. Regarding the fbsdk, the reason why I am doing it like this is because I was able to generate a accesstoken perfectly fine in here, but not with the fbsdk, problem with that is further explain in my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045983/issues-retrieving-fbsdk-access-token-and-user-id

Comment: Edited my question with new issue. For some reason the bridge needs a property declaration, other uses does not seem to need this, but this one does. And every declaration I've tried is wrong.

Comment: It was supposed to be declared as: @property (nonatomic, strong) RCTBridge *bridge;